# Show only posts that user has access

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this 3 tables, one post can be viewed by more than one user:

users

posts

user_posts

How I can do with Eloquent to show to the users only the posts that he has access?

Thanks

Comment: You would have to provide some information on what type of permissions you have set up for posts, or any methods you might have on the model to determine perms.

Comment: the only thing I want is that each user can only see in the backend table only those that are defined in the user_posts table, and not all the posts.

Comment: public function authorizedPosts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Post")->wherePivot('access', 1);
    }

Comment: also you can do it like this $posts= User::find(1)->posts()->where('access', 1)->get(); only if you defined relation like this { return $this->belongsToMany("App\Post")->withPivot('access'); } –

Comment: @Mendizalea also check https://laraveldaily.com/wherepivot-wherepivotin-additional-filters-many-many-relationships/ for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the models set up correctly, something like this on the **User Model**:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Post");
}
```

To get only those posts that a single user has created, try this in your **controller** (uses eager loading to limit the database queries):

```
 $user = \App\User::with('posts')->find($someInputUserId_orAuthUserId);

 $posts = $user->posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

- users table contain information of users with id
- posts table contains details posts with id, user_id
- userpost conatains information about users and the posts that they are accessed to with user_id and post_id.

> codes are

```php
//users.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class users extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\posts");
    }

    public function userPosts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\userpost");
    }
}
```

> post model

```php
//posts.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class posts extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\users");
    }
}
```

> userpost model (here user and post that they are accessed)

```php
//userpost.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class userpost extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\users");
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\posts","id","post_id");
    }
}
```

> controller can be written as

```php
//PostViewController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\posts;
use App\users;
use App\userpost;

class PostViewController extends Controller
{
    public function view()
    {
        $user_id = 2; //user_id of the user you want to view
        $posts= userpost::where('user_id', $user_id)->get(); 

        //return $posts; you can return $posts and view it on "view" by using foreach as shown below 
        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            return $user->posts;//posts is the function made in model.
        }

    }

}
```

> **here foreach loop is done only for once to get only one post as return ends the loop. It is only to show how to get data of post which can be done in view to get data**